# problem downloading origin EA please help

Tags: wine, games

OK I'm really getting angry! I wanna play a computer game (Sims 3) but I have to download origin first so I could play but it says this.

```
----- Archive:  /home/*****/Downloads/OriginThinSetup (1).exe
[/home/*****/Downloads/OriginThinSetup (1).exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/*****/Downloads/OriginThinSetup
------
```

Can someone explain in a way I can understand, what I can do to be able to play my game?   I'm so confused and I just want to play a game.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't installing wine...

Install wine, just right-click, hover `Open With...`, and choose Wine.